# Log-Likelihood of Piecewise-Defined Function

Tags: optimization, maximum-likelihood, sampling, log-likelihood

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4228803/log-likelihood-function-of-piecewise-defined-function), which might be too difficult. So I break the problem down. What I need to find is the log-likelihood of the following function:

$$f(x, a_{sg}, a_{pl}, p) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{1+\log_{n}(a_{sg})} & , x\leq Singulars \\
          min[\frac{1}{1+\log_{n}(a_{pl})}, \frac{1}{1+\log_{n}(a_{sg})}+p] & , x\leq Plurals
       \end{cases}$$

It would also be helpful for me to know how I could approach such a problem. An analytical solution is preferred, but I'd be happy also with an empirical approach, e.g. based on Bayesian sampling or similar.

Comment: What is the problem with writing down $\log f$ and similar?

Comment: Can you elaborate your thoughts? Maybe your point is obvious, but as I only have a very, very basic understanding of log-likelihoods, I don't know what you mean.